# On what conditions is a question automatically deleted?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question titled "Construction of a $k$-variety from a separated scheme of finite type over a field $k$" in December last year.
It was deleted yesterday by "Community".
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248792/construction-of-a-k-variety-from-a-separated-scheme-of-finite-type-over-a-fiel) is the link to the deleted question.
It had had no answer.
I think it got negative reps for the first time less than a week ago.
I think a question will be deleted if it has negative reps and has no answers for 30 days.
So I think it was deleted too early.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

A sufficient set of conditions for auto-deletion is:

- question is more than 30 days old
- has negative score
- has no answers
- is not locked

From what you said, your question met all of the above conditions.

There are also other reasons for auto-deletion, see [meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006).

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot.